# SublimeText 2: What does the number on the left side mean in command palette?

Tags: sublimetext2

When you search for a file name- on the left it gives you numbers ranging from 0-999. What do these numbers represent? It seems like a search ranking but I'm not sure.

[image: screenshot showing numbers on left of menu]

Comment: Screenshot?  Are those not just the line numbers in the file?

Comment: Since the numbers appear to be in descending order, I too would assume it's some sort of numerical ranking of how well the filename matches what you've typed in so far.

Answer (score 0):

They are a measure of the likelihood that the result will match your search query. This algorithm happens under the hood on most predictive or autocomplete searches (like Google's or Mac's Spotlight search) but the ST2 team decided it would be neat to show you the numeric result.

It takes a few items into consideration. Each one of these criteria adds more value to that result:

- ## of matching characters
- How frequently the file has been used
- Proximity to the top folder
- Whether the letters are in sequence or dispersed through the filename
- Whether the filename starts with the matched letters, or the matched letters are somewhere in between.

In the example below, you can see the values go up as "index.html" gradually becomes more accurate. As expected, buried files, or files that are used less frequently get a lower value.

[image: Example of increasing likelihood]